# Creating an Oracle SQL exception report?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to work on a SQL homework assignment, and I'm not having much luck with my textbooks (or google, for that matter) probably because I'm not searching exactly right. We're using "Oracle SQL by Example" in class and Oracle 10g for the DB. The instructor provided ZERO examples of how it's done in class.

The instructor presented a small DB (5 tables) for us to query on this assignment and we've been told to start creating exception reports using appropriate T-Title/header columns. We're supposed to check foreign key integrity and report errors on the different tables, and eventually updating a table to adjust the order totals and produce an error report on that.

The majority of the examples I've come across are for table creation. Since the tables are already created, can they still be used?

Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was over thinking the whole thing. An exception report is where you create a query, and double check the foreign key integrity (or PK integrity) to guard against orphans, and produce a query result that shows all the errors that do not match. You create a meaningful pseudo-column to describe what the results are actually displaying. You can then fix the errors by issuing an update command where needed.

```
SELECT order_num, 'Invalid Order Nums' "Order Numbers"
FROM order_table
where order_num NOT IN
--(or NOT EXISTS IN)
(select order_num
from order)
ORDER_NUM Order Numbers    
--------- ------------------
21615     Invalid Order Nums
```